# How I use composer autoloading?

Tags: composer-php

I have such project https://github.com/prazny/composer-autoload

What am I doing wrong?
 I would like to load class 'Writing' to composer.
index.php:

`Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\Writing\Writing' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\kurs\composer-autoload\index.php on line 4`

Comment: your classnames and filenames do not match. you've also chosen PSR-4 style autoloading, but gave a full path to a file instead of a directory that contains files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. **Problem:** Class/File name mismatch. **Solution:** Rename `./src/Writing/Write.php` to `./src/Writing/Writing.php`
2. **Problem:** PSR-4 autoloading standard compliance **Solution:** Change your PSR-4 config from `"": "src/Writing/Write.php"` to `"MyApp\\": "src/"`
3. Then regenerate your autoload file by running `composer dumpautoload`

Once you do all that, you'll get a fatal error in your `index.php` because you're trying to echo an instance of an object that does not have a `__toString`. This will tell you autoloading is working and that you need to fix your `index.php` code.

Also, you shouldn't commit the `vendor` directory. That, however, is an aside and is not causing the issues you're having.